# Gitlab 11: Create a branch from issue to another project

Tags: gitlab

We have a gitlab server which host 3 projects (front, back, issues) in the same group.

I'd like to know if its possible to create a branch on `front` project from an issue created on `issues` project ?

I tried in the issue page but it seems i can't select another project :

[image: gitlab branch creation from issue]

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **fully approve** @Ben Cassinat answer, it's not possible and not recommended at all.

**However**, you should use "[group board](https://about.gitlab.com/features/issueboard/)" which are different from project boards.

With them, you'll see **all issues of projects in the specified group**. **One board** for **multiple repositories** :)

Here is what it'll look like :[image: Gitlab group issues board]

Answer (score 2):

As far I know, that's not possible, and it's not a recommanded thing.

If you really need this, use branchs & tags to get the whole project under a single repository.

Gitlab handle the whole workspace arround repositories, like integrations, CI/CD, parameters ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ben. To go a bit further, our team would like to work around 2 separated repositories (front & back) but with only 1 board, do you think it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You could *[move the issue](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#moving-issues)* from the `issues` project to the `front` project - see the *Move* button on the right sidebar when viewing the issue.

Then you should be able to create a corresponding branch (or merge request) as expected within the `front` project (via the button you showed in your question).

Using a [group issue board](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issue_board.html#group-issue-boards) (see André's answer) you can track issues across your group of projects.

Note that GitLab Free currently only allows for a single group issue board (per group).